# BigQuery: Lookup array of IDs and join data from secondary table using SQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, join, google-bigquery

I have a data structure like below:

**Products**

```
| _id |  name  | available_in_region_id |
-----------------------------------------
| d22 |  shoe  | c32, a43, x53          |
| t64 |  hat   | c32, f42               |
```

**Regions**

```
| _id |  name       |
---------------------
| c32 |  london     |
| a43 |  manchester |
| x53 |  bristol    |
| f42 |  liverpool  |
```

I want to look up the array of "available_in_region_id" ids and replace them by the region name to result in a table like below:

```
| _id |  name  | available_in_region_name    |
----------------------------------------------
| d22 |  shoe  | london, manchester, bristol |
| t64 |  hat   | london, liverpool           |
```

What is the best way to do this using standard SQL?

Thanks,

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT p._id, p.name, 
  STRING_AGG(r.name, ', ' ORDER BY OFFSET) AS available_in_region_name
FROM `project.dataset.Products` p,
UNNEST(SPLIT(available_in_region_id, ', ')) rid WITH OFFSET
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.Regions` r
ON rid = r._id
GROUP BY _id, name
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.Products` AS (
  SELECT 'd22' _id, 'shoe' name, 'c32, a43, x53' available_in_region_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 't64', 'hat', 'c32, f42'
), `project.dataset.Regions` AS (
  SELECT 'c32' _id, 'london' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a43', 'manchester' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'x53', 'bristol' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'f42', 'liverpool' 
)
SELECT p._id, p.name, 
  STRING_AGG(r.name, ', ' ORDER BY OFFSET) AS available_in_region_name
FROM `project.dataset.Products` p,
UNNEST(SPLIT(available_in_region_id, ', ')) rid WITH OFFSET
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.Regions` r
ON rid = r._id
GROUP BY _id, name
```

with output

```
Row _id name    available_in_region_name     
1   d22 shoe    london, manchester, bristol  
2   t64 hat     london, liverpool
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but maybe the question was a bit misleading, but the IDs are not numerical, they are mongodb 12 bit objectIds, more like "3d42nd3nd32dd2278dn2". I'm assuming this won't work using "rid WITH OFFSET"

Comment: see updated answer to match changes in your question

Comment: Thanks. I get an error however:

No matching signature for function SPLIT for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<value STRING>>.

The field in question is type RECORD mode REPEATED

Comment: Sorry I am not from an SQL background so it's all a bit of a black box to me.

Comment: we all learning - consider also voting up the answer  - it is equally important here on SO

Comment: I have done. If you fancy looking at the updated question it's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62808554/bigquery-lookup-array-of-ids-type-record-and-join-data-from-secondary-table-usi

Comment: sure, I will. to vote up the question you should click on up-side arrow to the left of the answer - please do